# How to distinguish chinese fonts in Illustrator? (I can't read their chinese names)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I chose the fonts from a site so I know their latin name and what the font face looks like:

[image]

But when I want to choose them in illustrator to try and see how they look in my document with a specific text, they show up with their chinese name, and I can't identify them. They do show a small sample on the right but it's not enough to really see how they'll look in the document:

[image]

How would I do to identify them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preferences > Type > Show Font Names in English

[image]

This alters the font menu as indicated.

Comment: No need to be sorry :) No one knows that's there until someone points it out :)

Comment: But it was so obvious :D